# Is it possible to exclude a file from being deployed using aws codedeploy task from vsts

Tags: .net, azure-devops, aws-code-deploy

I want to make continuous integration tasks for my .net web application. I use aws codedeploy task for my application deployment.. Before ths deployment step (after the build step or even before it) I want to exclude my .config file and just keep the version deployed before on the server as is.. is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible.

You just need to copy the files you need to deploy to a different directory (such as `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\publish`).

Before AWS CodeDeploy Application Deployment task, add a **Copy Files task** with below settings:

Source Folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`

Contents: files you want to deploy

Target Folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\publish`

Then in the AWS CodeDeploy Application Deployment task, specify the **Revision Bundle** as `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\publish`.

More details, you can refer [Deploying .NET Web Applications Using AWS CodeDeploy with Visual Studio Team Services](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploying-net-web-applications-using-aws-codedeploy-with-visual-studio-team-services/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! that helped me alot